# Bug in Python Renaming Program.....No such file or Directory (Fnmatch)

Tags: python, rename

I'm trying to build a little renaming program to help save me time in the future.
Basically it will go through directories I point it too and rename files if they meet certain criteria.

I have written what I need but I have a bug in the very beginning that I can't figure out.

Here is the code:

```
import os
import fnmatch

for file in os.listdir("""/Users/Desktop/TESTME"""):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'MISC*'):
        os.rename(file, file[4:12] + '-13-Misc.jpg')
```

When I try to run it I am getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/Try.py", line 6, in <module>
    os.rename(file, file[4:12] + '-13-Misc.jpg')
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I also tried this:

```
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file,'MISC*'):
    fun = file[4:12] + '-13-Misc.jpg'
    os.rename(file, fun)
```

But I get the same thing.

It's not recognizing the file as a file.
Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to include the *full path* to the filenames you are trying to rename:

```
import os
import fnmatch

directory = "/Users/Desktop/TESTME"
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, 'MISC*'):
        path = os.path.join(directory, file)
        target = os.path.join(directory, file[4:12] + '-13-Misc.jpg'
        os.rename(path, target)
```

The [`os.path.join` function](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) intelligently joins path elements into a whole, using the correct directory separator for your platform.

Answer (score 1):

The function `os.listdir()` only returns the file names of the files in the given directory, not their full paths.  You can use `os.path.join(directory, file_name)` to reconstruct the full path of the file.

You could also do this in bash:

```
cd /Users/Desktop/TESTME/
for f in MISC*; do mv "$f" "${f:4:8}-13-Misc.jpg"; done
```