# Python 2.7.11 os.rename issues and weird execution order

Tags: python, execution

I'm trying to write a simple script to check if a file has numbers in its name, and to delete them if it does. Here's my code:

```
import os

directory = raw_input("Enter a path string: ")
print "This will now delete all numbers from the files in %s." %directory

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    print filename
    for s in filename:
        if s.isdigit():
            print filename
            path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
            print path
            target = os.path.join(directory, filename.replace(s, ""))
            print target
            os.rename(path, target)

print "Done."
```

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "EditFilename.py", line 15, in <module>
os.rename(path, target)
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
```

Which is weird, since `path` is clearly defined. If I define `path` above the for loop as `path = "Nothing"` then I get this error:

```
File "EditFilename.py", line 16, in <module>
os.rename(path, target)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm following what apparently worked from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294034/bug-in-python-renaming-program-no-such-file-or-directory-fnmatch) link, but I can't get my code to work. It seems like the line `os.rename(path, target)` is being executed before the line `path = os.path.join(directory, filename)`!

Thanks in advance for your help, after four hours of google I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your indentation is correct? Maybe the `rename` line is not inside the `if` block at all.

Comment: The `NameError` you are getting probably means you haven't properly restarted Python between runs of your script. The code you posted here won't throw a `NameError`, no.

Comment: Looking at the source of the question, it seems like you are mixing tabs and spaces. _Don't do that!_

Comment: Not a direct answer but why don't you use regular expressions (`re`) for it? http://pastebin.com/c81WtXP0

Comment: I was not aware that a module like this existed.  Thanks for bringing it to my attention, I'm still reading up on it, but it looks like it may simplify things further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the markup source of your question, it seems like you are mixing tabs and spaces for your Python indentation. Don't do this! This can severely confuse your Python interpreter and cause individual lines to be associated with different blocks than they should be.

It's difficult to determine how exactly your indentation was, because of the extra-indentation for the code block in the question, however, the first three lines in your `if` block as indented with 3 tabs and 4 spaces, and the following three lines with 8 spaces, 1 tab, and 4 more spaces.

Thus, what your Python interpreter is seeing is probably more like this:

```
for s in filename:
    if s.isdigit():
        print filename
        path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        print path
    target = os.path.join(directory, filename.replace(s, ""))
    print target
    os.rename(path, target)
```

That is, the `os.rename` line is *always* executed, even if `path` was not previously defined in the `if` block, and if you define `path = "Nothing"` at the start, it will still have that value when Python hits the first `os.rename`.

To fix this, simply convert all the indentation to either tabs or spaces (which to use is somewhat a [question of taste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119562/tabs-versus-spaces-in-python-programming)). Most text editors will do this for you if just indent and then de-dent everything (i.e. press Ctrl-A, Tab, Shift-Tab).

Comment: This was it, thank you very much! I'm still getting used to the fact that indentation matters to the interpreter.

Answer (score 3):

The code you posted won't throw a `NameError`; make sure you properly restarted Python before running code you edited.

However, you do have other problems that'll lead to an `OSError`. You never exit your `for s in filename:` loop. So if there is more than one digit in your filename, you try to rename it multiple times:

```
>>> filename = 'hunter42'
>>> for s in filename:
...     if s.isdigit():
...         print 'renaming {} to {}'.format(filename, filename.replace(s, ''))
...
renaming hunter42 to hunter2
renaming hunter42 to hunter4
```

Since `hunter42` was already renamed to `hunter2`, you can't rename it again to another name.

Use the [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) instead, to test for digits just once, instead of in a `for` loop:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if any(s.isdigit() for s in filename):
        path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        target = os.path.join(directory, filename.translate(None, '0123456789'))
        os.rename(path, target)
```

I used [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to remove digits from the filename here:

```
>>> filename.translate(None, '01234567890')
'hunter'
```

You could also *first* translate the name, and if it is different from the original, *then* rename:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    newname = filename.translate(None, '0123456789')
    if filename != newname:
        path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
        target = os.path.join(directory, newname)
        os.rename(path, target)
```

Comment: While this is certainly true, I don't see how renaming the file multiple times would cause either that name error OP is experiencing or the "no such file" error...

Comment: @tobias_k: because the old file has *already* been renamed, you can't rename it again.

Comment: @tobias_k: after renaming `hunter42` to `hunter2`, trying to rename `hunter42` to `hunter4` won't work.. Note that the `filename` reference is *unchanged* in the loop!

Comment: Ah, right, `filename` is not updated, the new name is only stored in `target`... but still, the `NameError` has to have some other reason (see my comment on the question).

Comment: The `NameError` was being thrown due to the indentation issue, like tobias_k said.  I was not aware the `any()` and `filename.translate` methods existed, and I have implemented them.  Thank you both your help!

Comment: @LWKatze: ah, yes, that'd explain the error too. I strongly recommend you configure your editor to always use spaces for indentation, that way you can continue to use the TAB key to indent, but you'll not hit this issue with the indentation being ambiguous (e.g. when you configure your editor to use 4 spaces for each tab stop, Python uses 8).

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Thanks for the additional tip. I'm starting to realize a lot of the errors I've been getting are due to indentation errors I don't see.